# Angular: How to pass boolean async variable in template function?

Tags: angular, templates, rxjs

We can get async pipe as variable with *ngIf

```
<button *ngIf="account$ | async as account" (click)="parseAccount(account)" type="button"></button>
```

But of course it won't work for boolean values, for example

```
<button *ngIf="loggedIn$ | async as loggedIn" (click)="checkAuth(loggedIn)" type="button"></button>
```

Because `loggedIn$ | async` can emit false.

Is there any other built-in way to get async values as template variable without custom ngInit directives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found an answer

```
<button *ngIf="{ val: loggedIn$ | async } as loggedIn" (click)="checkAuth(loggedIn.val)" type="button"></button>
```

Maybe a little bit hacky but works

Note that `*ngIf` is used here not for visibility but as a way to get a template variable

Comment: Be aware, that this makes the button instantly visible

Comment: @dewey yes, but that is expected since `*ngIf` is used here as a hack to get a variable in the template
You basically don't need to provide anything to a callback if it is not visible
And if visible - you can just provide `true`
I've edited my answer